# Do.. Loop Until with multiple IFs

Tags: vba, loops, excel

I need your help. I want to add a `Do ... Loop Until' to my code.

All I want to do is to change the range automatically and perform all logical tests from cell O2 as a starting point of my code until cell O1700 which got the value of `"END"`

So if the value of O2 = "NA" then do all the IFs if not just skip to the next cell and perform the AvtiveCell = "NA" again and again untill "END".

I've added something like this but its not working properly it just find the first "NA" cell and then stops.

```
    Range ("O2").Select

    IF (ActiveCell = "NA") THEN
    'MY CODE

    ELSE
    DO
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop Until (ActiveCell = "END")
```

your help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Do you mean `NA` or `#N/A`? If the latter, I believe you need to check the cell's error state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
Dim lLoop as long

lloop=2

do while cells(lloop,1)<>"END"
if cells(lloop,1)="NA" then
'my code
end if
lloop=lloop+1
loop
```

If possible, avoid selecting cells unless you want to display the selection change to the user. It slows down processes and generally complicates coding.

Answer (score 1):

The `If` must be *inside* the loop:

```
range("O2").Select
do
    if ActiveCell = "NA" then
        ' Your code goes here
    else
        ' If you want to do something if the cell is not "NA"
    end if
    ActiveCell.Offset(1,0).Select
loop until ActiveCell = "End"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim counter As Integer
counter = 2
Do
    If Range("O" & counter) = "NA" Then
        'Your code
    End If
    counter = counter + 1
Loop Until Range("O" & counter) = "END"
```

P.S.

1. You can indent your code to enhance the readability.
2. As someone has already mentioned, are you looking for `#N/A` instead of `NA`
3. Avoid using `Select` as it slows down your code. It may also lower the maintainability.

Comment: thanks it worked beautifully, and yes im looking for NA values not the error #N/A.